# Python: Interruptable threading in wx

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

My wx GUI shows thumbnails, but they're slow to generate, so:

- The program should remain usable while the thumbnails are generating.
- Switching to a new folder should stop generating thumbnails for the old folder.
- If possible, thumbnail generation should make use of multiple processors.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is your thumbnail generation actually CPU-bound? If not, there's no reason to use multiple cores, and everything gets a lot easier.

Comment: Also, if the thumbnail generation is the _only_ thing that's slow, and you don't need multiple cores, you can do this without any multithreading. If you make the jobs small enough, you can do one job each time through the event loop. (If a single thumbnail is too big a job, you can always use a generator to yield every so often, and just call `next(job)` once per event loop, or use `wx.SafeYield`.) I didn't recommend this in my answer because I think for thumbnail generation and a wx GUI, you probably are better off using a thread, but the option is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the thumbnail generation in a background thread with `threading.Thread` will solve your first problem, making the program usable.

If you want a way to interrupt it, the usual way is to add a "stop" variable which the background thread checks every so often (e.g., once per thumbnail), and the GUI thread sets when it wants to stop it. Ideally you should protect this with a `threading.Condition`. (The condition isn't actually necessary in most cases—the same GIL that prevents your code from parallelizing well also protects you from certain kinds of race conditions. But you shouldn't rely on that.)

For the third problem, the first question is: Is thumbnail generation actually CPU-bound? If you're spending more time reading and writing images from disk, it probably isn't, so there's no point trying to parallelize it. But, let's assume that it is.

First, if you have N cores, you want a pool of N threads, or N-1 if the main thread has a lot of work to do too, or maybe something like 2N or 2N-1 to trade off a bit of best-case performance for a bit of worst-case performance.

However, if that CPU work is done in Python, or in a C extension that nevertheless holds the Python GIL, this won't help, because most of the time, only one of those threads will actually be running.

One solution to this is to switch from threads to processes, ideally using the standard `multiprocessing` module. It has built-in APIs to create a pool of processes, and to submit jobs to the pool with simple load-balancing.

The problem with using processes is that you no longer get automatic sharing of data, so that "stop flag" won't work. You need to explicitly create a flag in shared memory, or use a pipe or some other mechanism for communication instead. The `multiprocessing` docs explain the various ways to do this.

You *can* actually just kill the subprocesses. However, you may not want to do this. First, unless you've written your code carefully, it may leave your thumbnail cache in an inconsistent state that will confuse the rest of your code. Also, if you want this to be efficient on Windows, creating the subprocesses takes some time (not as in "30 minutes" or anything, but enough to affect the perceived responsiveness of your code if you recreate the pool every time a user clicks a new folder), so you probably want to create the pool before you need it, and keep it for the entire life of the program.

Other than that, all you have to get right is the job size. Hopefully creating one thumbnail isn't too big of a job—but if it's too small of a job, you can batch multiple thumbnails up into a single job—or, more simply, look at the `multiprocessing` API and change the way it batches jobs when load-balancing.

Meanwhile, if you go with a pool solution (whether threads or processes), if your jobs are small enough, you may not really need to cancel. Just drain the job queue—each worker will finish whichever job it's working on now, but then sleep until you feed in more jobs. Remember to also drain the queue (and then maybe join the pool) when it's time to quit.

One last thing to keep in mind is that if you successfully generate thumbnails as fast as your computer is capable of generating them, you may actually cause the whole computer—and therefore your GUI—to become sluggish and unresponsive. This usually comes up when your code is actually I/O bound and you're using most of the disk bandwidth, or when you use lots of memory and trigger swap thrash, but if your code really is CPU-bound, and you're having problems because you're using all the CPU, you may want to either use 1 fewer core, or look into setting thread/process priorities.

Comment: +1 for a thoughtful explanation of the issues involved in concurrency.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm not sure whether the thumbnail generation is CPU bound. Is there any easy way to tell?

Comment: So I use a stop variable to ask the thread to stop. But how do I wait for it to actually stop?

Comment: @AlanLynn: The first check is to see if your CPU usage goes to 100% while it's happening. Ideally, pull the thumbnail generation out into a non-GUI app and see if _it_ uses 100%. And see if most of your time is user time (as opposed to system time, or whatever the Windows equivalent is). If the answers to any of those are no, you're probably not CPU-bound; if they're all yes, you may be.

Comment: @AlanLynn: Do you actually need to wait for it to stop? If you do, you can use another `Condition`—the main thread waits on it and sets the stop flag, the background thread notifies the condition when it sees the flag and stops. Or you can just let the thread exit when it's done (either because there's no more work to do, or because of the stop flag), and have the main thread call `join` once it asks the background thread to stop. The second version may not be appropriate if you're using processes instead of threads.

Comment: Generating thumbnails does put one CPU to 100%. I don't know how to find the user time to system time ratio.

Comment: @AlanLynn: If you're on Mac, Linux, or most other Unix-like systems, and you've done what I suggested earlier and pulled the thumbnail generation out into a non-GUI app for testing, just run `time myscript.py`, or use `resource.getrusage` from inside the script. If you're on Windows, I don't know what the equivalent is. (If you want help with this, you should probably actually say what platform you're on, so I don't have to keep giving suggestions in the form "do this on Unix, or that on Windows", etc.)

Comment: I'm on Windows. I saw you mention Windows earlier and assumed you knew somehow.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing with Conditions. I use condition.wait() to wait for the thread to do condition.notify(). But condition.wait() seems to halt the thread's execution, preventing it from getting to condition.notify().

Comment: Using wx.CallAfter seemed to fix that problem.

Comment: I now have working single-processor code. The key seemed to be moving wx stuff into `wx.CallAfter` to make it threadsafe. However, this would sometimes cause unwanted CallAfter updates to occur after stopping the thread. I solved this by making the CallAfter updates check if they still made sense.

Comment: I'll leave multiprocessing stuff for a future version, though any further information on that is quite welcome.

Comment: @AlanLynn: You use a `Condition` to communicate between two threads, not within one thread. The main thread calls `wait`, the background thread calls `notify`. If you call both in the same thread, you're guaranteed to block forever.

Comment: @AlanLynn: I probably didn't say it explicitly enough, but what I was trying to get at is that multithreading is hard, unless you have small tasks, and you don't need multithreading if you have small tasks, so don't do the hard stuff if you don't have to. I was thinking of either using a generator to break your tasks up so small that you can do them from the event loop, or a design around `SafeYield`—but `CallAfter` is probably an even simpler way to do it. So I'm glad you discovered it on your own, and it's working for you.